# ε vs u as the error term in regression

Tags: regression, terminology, notation

Keeping in mind regression model equations of the following general type

$$Y = β_0 + β_1X_1 + β_2X_2 + ε$$

I notice that although $ε$ is usually given as the error term, sometimes the error term is denoted as $u$ instead.

My question is: is there some difference between the contexts in which $ε$ is used and $u$ is used?

From googling and from memory I notice that the capital $U$ is used sometimes, while I've never seen capital $E$ used. Are $u$/$U$ more typically associated with some matrix representation of regression?

Comment: @Tim is right; at the same time there are many widespread conventions which would be perverse or awkward to ignore or defy. Anyone you wanted to use $X$ for response and $Y$ for predictor would likely be asked to revise that choice by any decent statistical journal. I guess that most people would avoid $E$ because of its entrenched use for expectation.

Comment: My own personel observation is that $\varepsilon$ is typically used in statistical papers, whereas $u$ is often found in econometrics. I think must people are likely to understand both, I see no reason why one is superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are free to use any notation they want. There is no "single objective" meaning of $\varepsilon$. If you want, you can as well write regression equation as $X = \varepsilon_0 + \varepsilon_1 Y_1 + \varepsilon_2 Y_2 + \beta$. To give other examples, $\pi$ is a number, but it is also commonly used to denote parameters of different models, e.g. parameters of [latent class analysis models](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i10)

$$
f(Y_i;\pi_r) = \prod_{j=1}^J \prod_{k=1}^{K_j} (\pi_{ijk})^{Y_{ijk}}
$$

See other questions tagged [notation](/questions/tagged/notation) to learn that notation is arbitrary.

All this said, it is worth emphasizing that you should be clear about the notation you are using (define the meaning of your symbols) and try to be consistent with the conventions in your field. If people in your field more commonly use $\varepsilon$, then use it, if they more commonly use $u$, use it instead. Notice however that there are cases when you want to use different notation, e.g. people commonly use $\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots$ for regression parameters, but if you already used $\beta$ symbols for something else, then it may be wiser to use other symbols not to confuse your reader. So in the end we *want* the notation to be flexible, the same as human language is flexible, because there are cases when we need to say something using different words/symbols.